# How to run a spesific code right after the event of DataGridView.Sort complete

Tags: c#, winforms

On my DataGridView's Sort event I use this code:

```
if (e.Column.Index == 7 || e.Column.Index == 9)
{
    e.SortResult = double.Parse(e.CellValue1.ToString()).CompareTo(double.Parse(e.CellValue2.ToString()));
    e.Handled = true;//pass by the default sorting
}
```

which does the sorting assuming the data is double type.

after that sort event run, my background coloring mixes up.
I want to repaint all but couldn't find how to trigger another code after DataGridView.Sort event does its job.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Note: Please don't tell me to create a timer that checks a variable that holds the value if the datagridview sorted or not every second, if it changes run another code. That's not a good solution I think.

Comment: Normally I do all sorting/invalidating on the underlying bindingsource instead of the datagridview, but the datagridview does seem to have a `Sorted` event (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sorted) If you put a `youDataGridView.Invalidate()` in there?

Comment: Sir, Thank you so much for your comment. Please Excuse my ignorance, How should I use that "youDataGridView.Invalidate()", I am not a very good programmer, just a regular one try to improve myself.

Comment: It depends on the DataSource of your DGV. If it's a `List<class>`, `BindingList<class>`, use these lists as the DataSource of a BindingSource and set the BindingSource as the DataSource of your DGV, then use the BindingSource to sort the data. If the DGV's datasource is a DataTable, you already have these functionality, just use them, the same if you use some kind of ORM. I.e., don't sort the control, sort the data and use an appropriate DataSource for your DGV.